"Fetch type out of range" error when using MovePrev to fetch stored procedure
There is code that works with the Visual Studio 2010 platform toolset, but does not work with platform toolsets higher than Visual Studio 2010.
The following example is greatly simplified to demonstrate the problem.
Stored Procedure for MS SQL Server
create proc dbo.TestStoredProc
as
begin
    declare @rc1 int = 1
    declare @rc2 int = 2
 
    select @rc1
        union all
    select @rc2
end
go

C++ code with using MFC
#include "afxdb.h"
 
class CTestRecordset : public CRecordset
{
public:
    CTestRecordset(CDatabase* pDatabase = NULL) :
        CRecordset(pDatabase)
    {
        m_nFields = 1;
    };
 
    int m_rc;
 
    virtual void DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX);
};
 
void CTestRecordset::DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX)
{
    pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputColumn);
    RFX_Int(pFX, (LPCTSTR)"rc", m_rc);
}
 
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CDatabase db;
    db.OpenEx((LPCTSTR)"DSN=ODBCName;UID=Login;PWD=Password", CDatabase::useCursorLib | CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
    CTestRecordset rs(&db);
 
    rs.Open(CRecordset::snapshot, (LPCTSTR)"{CALL TestStoredProc}", CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::executeDirect | CRecordset::noDirtyFieldCheck);

    CString t; 
    t.Format("Open: %d", rs.m_rc);
    ::AfxMessageBox(t); // will output the number 1
 
    rs.MoveNext();
    t.Format("MoveNext: %d", rs.m_rc);
    ::AfxMessageBox(t); // will output the number 2
 
    rs.MovePrev();
    t.Format("MovePrev: %d", rs.m_rc);
    ::AfxMessageBox(t); // will output the number 1
 
    rs.Close();
    db.Close();
}

When running this code with a toolchain higher than Visual Studio 2010 (e.g. Visual Studio 2022 (v143)), an error will occur on the rs.MovePrev() line with the error text "Fetch type out of range"
I started the SQL profiler and started stepping through the C++ code.
At the line rs.Open(CRecordset::snapshot, (LPCTSTR)"{CALL TestStoredProc}", CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::executeDirect | CRecordset::noDirtyFieldCheck) the SQL profiler showed 2 messages:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword "declare".
SQL statement executed directly; no cursor.

The second message explains why the error occurred in rs.MovePrev(), because the cursor was forcibly canceled.
Tell me what can be done? Because of this problem we cannot switch to a set of platform tools higher than Visual Studio 2010.

This is a huge project written using Visual Studio 2010 and is used by many organizations. This project also has a huge number of stored procedures written and running for a long time. There was an attempt to migrate the project to Visual Studio 2022 using the latest platform toolset, which led to these issues. All examples that were given in this thread are greatly simplified to demonstrate the problem.


(LPCTSTR)"rc" -- (LPCTSTR)"{CALL TestStoredProc}" -- Why are you casting this to LPCTSTR?  This cast only works if the application is ANSI/MBCS -- if the character set type is Unicode, this is not going to work.  If you removed the cast, do you get a compile error?  If so, please read the error carefully, as it will tell you the types are not compatible.

This is not a bug. My project does not support unicode.

Then the cast is unnecessary.  Casting strings like this will always have the suspicion of the code having a bug.  It conveys that the cast is covering up a compiler error.
